# How can we find the element in a dataset, that satisfies the given condition and its sequential number in the dataset (C++)?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, for-loop

The first line of the standard input contains the number of elements(N) (1<=N<=100). The next lines contain a number (M) (1<=M<=300), as we know, there can be maximum 100 "M" elements.

We need to find the smallest number, that is larger than 120. In the first line of the standard output, we need to print the sequential number (which "M" number) and the value of that element and there should be a space between them. If there is no number, that satisfies the given conditions, then the program should print -1. If there are more elements, that satisfy the condition, then the program should print the one with the smaller sequential number. We should get exactly the same output, as in the example, otherwise it doesn't work.

For example:

Input:

6

118

200

199

116

200

122

Output:
6 122

So far, I wrote the following code, I think, that this puts the numbers, that are smaller than 120 into a vector. From this, we need to sort out the correct element and give the conditions. I am not sure, if this code works even for sorting out the numbers larger than 120, but I write this code to show, that I have been trying for a long time with a lot of codes, but I got really stuck.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main(){
vector<int> v;
int N, M, counter = 0;
cin >> N >> M;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
if (M < 120) {
counter++;
v.push_back(i+1);
}
}
for (vector<int>::iterator itr = v.begin(); itr != v.end(); ++itr)
{

}
return 0;

}
```

Please keep in mind, that I am a beginner yet, so answer my question in that manner. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Do you mean, "smallest number that is *greater* than 120", or "*largest* number that is smaller than 120"? Your description is unclear.

Comment: There is no need to use a vector or anything like that to accomplish the given task. This only overcomplicates things by several orders of magnitude, and makes everything too convoluted, for no good reason. This simple task can be done simply by reading the input file, one line at a time, and keeping track of everything in a couple of variables: the smallest value read so far that's less than 120, and its line number. This can be done with a simple loop, and a little bit of logic. No need for any kind of a vector, or sorting, or anything like that.

Comment: Yes, I meant smallest number that is greater than 120. Sorry for the confusing description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I thought of after reading your question and looking at the input. I think you made a small mistake in your question - it should be smallest number greater than 120. Check out the code given below:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int n, ans = INT_MAX, pos = -1;
  cin >> n;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    if (x > 120 && x < ans) {
      ans = x;
      pos = i + 1;
    }
  }
  if (pos != -1)
    cout << pos << ' ' << ans;
  else
    cout << -1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a very elegant and correct solution, works perfectly. Also very nice, that you spotted the mistake and still gave a correct solution.